# How do I fix SASL authentication failure

Tags: smtp, centos7, vps, postfix-mta, dovecot

I'm trying to set up an email server on Centos 7 using postfix and dovecot.

whenever I telnet into my server, I get kicked out:

```
[root@mail log]# telnet mail.mydomain.com smtp
Trying IP ADDRESS...
Connected to mail.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When I check the logs in /var/log/maillog this is the error I see:

```
Mar 15 05:33:44 vultr postfix/smtps/smtpd[20434]: connect from ***********
Mar 15 05:33:44 vultr postfix/smtps/smtpd[20434]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Internal Error -4 in server.c near line 1757
Mar 15 05:33:44 vultr postfix/smtps/smtpd[20434]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Internal Error -4 in server.c near line 1757
Mar 15 05:33:44 vultr postfix/smtps/smtpd[20434]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Internal Error -4 in server.c near line 1757
Mar 15 05:33:44 vultr postfix/smtps/smtpd[20434]: warning: xsasl_cyrus_server_get_mechanism_list: no mechanism available
Mar 15 05:33:44 vultr postfix/smtps/smtpd[20434]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Mar 15 05:33:45 vultr postfix/master[18735]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 20434 exit status 1
Mar 15 05:33:45 vultr postfix/master[18735]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you compile postfix/dovecot from source or install from yum repo?